# Problem with nested Tables

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

I have a function `r`, which removes the first instance of an element of a list

```
r[m_, el_] := Delete[m, First@First@Position[m, el]]
```

I also have nested tables and `n` is the number of nested tables, so in this example `n=4`

```
Table[
  Table[
    Table[
      Table[
        {i, j, k, l, Total@T - i - j - k - l},
        {i, r[r[r[T, l], k], j]}
      ], {j, r[r[T, l], k]}
    ], {k, r[T, l]}
  ], {l, T}
]
```

And I want `n` to be variable, so if `n=2`, the nested tables should be

```
Table[
  Table[
    {i, j, Total@T - i - j},
    {i, r[T, j]}
  ], {j, T}
]
```

---

The goal is to have a function that takes `n` and `T` as arguments and outputs this nested table.

Note that in each argument of each `Table` the range is almost an element of `NestList[r[#,l]&,T,n]`, but it's not exactly that. Because `l` in this example is different in each iteration.

**EDIT:**

Imagine that to do a task you need to do `n` subtasks, and each subtask needs some time to be done. This is `T`. When finishing a subtask `t_i` you need some time to get to the start of another subtask and I want to find the order in which you need to do the tasks to make it the most efficient.

Comment: This looks somewhat complicated; perhaps a simpler solution might exist, but could you show an example of your desired final output for some specific values of `n` and `T`?

Comment: *Very* inelegant coding, which doesn't exploit the natural efficiencies and functions of *Mathematica*.

Comment: Considering your last statement about `NestList`, then perhaps `FoldList` could work for you, if you use a list of the values of `l` that are of interest.

Comment: @MarcoB Edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Garmekain Thank you for the edit, but could you state the problem more clearly? I don't immediately see the relationship between the values in `T` and the elements of the matrix to be considered. A really good idea would be to take an actual matrix, with some random numbers in it (say for instance `SeedRandom[1]; RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {4, 4}]`), and actual value of `T`, such as perhaps the one you used above, and show us the actual output you seek. I am almost positive that the nested `Table` can be improved upon, but I'm afraid that I can't help if I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: @MarcoB Edited the question again.

Comment: There is probably a much better way to tackle the problem, but the description is hard to understand. You have a list `T` and you're trying to find a length `n` subset of `T` that satisfies some unspecified condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be better ways to do this, but here is how literally to build up your nested table for variable `n` :

```
r[m_, el_?NumericQ] := Delete[m, First@First@Position[m, el]]
```

Note the function `r` has to be fixed to only evaluate for numeric arguments.

Your original table for `n=4`:

```
T = {1, 2, 3, 2, 1}
a = Table[
  Table[Table[
    Table[{i, j, k, l, Total@T - i - j - k - l},
      {i, r[r[r[T, l], k], j]}], {j, r[r[T, l], k]}],
      {k, r[T, l]}], {l,T}];
```

first write as a single nested `Table`. Note the iterator ordering is outside to inside left to right:

```
Table[{i, j, k, l, Total@T - i - j - k - l}, {l, T}, {k, r[T, l]}, {j,
    r[r[T, l], k]}, {i, r[r[r[T, l], k], j]}] == a
```

> True

then construct the lists for variable `n`:

```
n = 4
iters = Table[Unique[], {n}];
itlist = Transpose[{Reverse@iters, FoldList[r, T, Reverse@Rest@iters]}];
expr = Append[iters, Total@T - Total@iters];
Table[expr, Evaluate[Sequence @@ itlist]] == a
```

> True

Comment: btw, I think `r[m_, el_?NumericQ] := Delete[m, First@First@Position[m, el]]` can be simplified to `r[m_, el_?NumericQ] := Delete[m, First@Position[m, el]]` i.e. remove one of those `First` ;)

Comment: yes, `Delete` takes an integer or a list with one integer the same.

Comment: @george2079 My bad, I understood that I needed to put Evaluates to use iters as part specifications.